# Find out whether time is updated automatically

Tags: settings, time

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and KDE.

The checkbox **Set date and time automatically** in **Date & Time - System Settings** is greyed out. Not sure how to understand it. Is the time updated automatically or not? Are there any command to find it out? And if it's not updated automatically how to activate this option?

Comment: What do you get for `timedatectl timesync-status` ?

Comment: @DougSmythies The output is `Failed to query server: The name org.freedesktop.timesync1 was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: @DougSmythies `sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd` solved the problem. Thanks. Not sure how and when it was removed...

Comment: @ka3ak Your last comment is actually the solution to your issue and is better posted as an answer, which you can also mark as the solution. I have posted it as a Community Wiki answer (so I won't get any rep from that) for the time being, until you post an answer yourself if you wish. If you do post the answer, please let me know by pinging me here so I can delete the CW, or flag the CW for a mod to delete it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd` solved the problem. Thanks. Not sure how and when it was removed...

<sup>Solution from [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451114/find-out-whether-time-is-updated-automatically#comment2533980_1451114).</sup>